# nested ng-repeat with outer ng-repeat item affecting the inner ng-repeat logic

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code

```
<div ng-repeat='n in [] | range:(my_works.items.length/3)+1'>
    <div class="table-row" style="position:absolute;left:13px;{{row_gap_style(n)}}" class='ng-scope'>
         <div class="book_container" ng-repeat='item in my_works.items.slice($index*3,($index*3+3))' style="position:absolute;top:0px;{{col_gap_style($index)}}">
            <div id="" title="{{ item.Story.title}}" class="cover_container fetched {{check_published(item)}}" rel="<?php echo $rel; ?>">
```

What I want to do is

if `n` in the outer ng-repeat is 0, then the div.book_container will look like this instead:

```
<div class="book_container" ng-show="n == 0" ng-repeat='item in my_works.items.slice($index*2, ($index*2+2))' style="position:absolute;top:0px;{{col_gap_style($index+1)}}">
```

otherwise, the div should be as before.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Include both div elements and add an ng-if directive to both; one containing n == 0 and the other n != 0.

Comment: what about the elements inside the inner ng-repeat? ideally i don't have to repeat them. I am referring the div.cover_container etc

Answer (score 1):

You could create a directive for the same content and then use ng-if to set different attributes dependent on the value of n:

```
.directive('bookContainer', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      'items': '=',
      'colstyle': '@'
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<p ng-repeat="item in items">book: {{item}} {{colstyle}}</p>'
  };
});
```

View:

```
<div ng-repeat='n in []'>
    <book-container ng-if='n==0' items='my_works.slice($index,1)' colstyle='s1'></book-container>
    <book-container ng-if='n!=0' items='my_works.slice($index,2)' colstyle='s2'></book-container>
</div>
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/8Kwrc/)</kbd>

The demo has been greatly simplified but shows the technique which you could hopefully use.